# How to set cron schedule dynamically from database?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, cron, crontab

I have a module which is basically a grid and has entry for different jobs. Each entry here represent a cron and all these crons are mentioned in `crontab.xml`. Now I need to use the schedule from a Job entry present in the grid. 
For eaxmple : Cron1, I want to use Job1 schedule from database.

I know we can use `config_path` from **system settings** but here it is not configuration it is present in the table of a collection so I can not put path of config directly.

Thanks..!